# How to write the matrices for Hadamard gates acting on differen qubits?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

Can anyone explain the process required to make a Hadamard gate that acts on 1st, 2nd and 3rd qbits?

For Hgates acting on the first qubit i realise the matrix is $H=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, but I am unsure how to formulate such a gate. As to acting on the second qubit I have read this [web page 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform) but I am not really sure if it is correct, because it is just a 4x4 matrix without any zeroes. I found this $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\-1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $ on another website which will obviously have zeroes when it is multiplied by $I$. Simply can anyone explain how Hadarmd gates can be formulated and built to n qubits?

Comment: The web page talks about a *Hadamard transform* and not a *Hadamard gate*. To perform a Hadamard transform to an $n$-qubit state, you apply a Hadamard gate to each qubit individually. So the website is correct, but it doesn't directly apply to your question.

Answer (score 8):

For two qubits, the answer is as follows.

The Hadamard gate acting on the second qubit is  $I \otimes H$:

$$ A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1&1&0&0\\
1&-1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&-1
\end{array}
\right).
$$

The Hadamard gate acting on the first qubit is $H \otimes I$:

$$ B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
1&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&-1
\end{array}
\right).
$$

For three qubits, the matrices for the Hadamard gate on the 3rd, 2nd, and 1st qubits are

$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc} A & 0 \\ 0 & A \end{array}\right), $$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc} B & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{array}\right), $$
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{array}{rr} I & I \\ I & -I \end{array}\right). $$

Hopefully, you can see the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I want to give a clarification for those using Qiskit or QuEST: when talking about the 'first', 'second' or 'nth' qubit in an n-qubits circuit, you have to flip the circuit 90° clockwise and count from left to right so that:

X = 'first qubit'

Y = 'second qubit'

Applying the Hadamard gate to the 'second qubit = Y' means performing: I⊗H

Applying the Hadamard gate to the 'first qubit = X' means performing:  H⊗I

Bottom line: ***Make sure you know the convention for tagging qubits as 'first', 'second' or 'nth'***

Search on YouTube (min 11): Understanding Quantum Information and Computation | Lesson 3 | Quantum Circuits

**If this is your circuit:**
[image]

**..you flip it 90° clockwise**
[image]

**..to apply Hadamard gate on the 'second qubit = Y' apply the I matrix on the 'first qubit = X'**
[image]
**..then composing the gates goes from the gates of the 'first qubit = X' (CNOT) to the 'second qubit = Y' (Hadamard): CNOT⊗H**
[image]
Applying the Hadamard gate to the 'nth qubit = Z' means performing: (I⊗I⊗..⊗I)^(n-1)⊗H

*This clarification becomes useful when testing on Qiskit or QuEST the application of the Hadamard gate on your qubits so the mathematical results will correspond with Qiskit or QuEST simulations.*